# Calculating sleep duration (before and after midnight) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to calculate the total number of minutes spent in bed overnight by inputting the time entered bed (e.g. 9pm) and time exited bed (e.g. 6am).
Using those example inputs, the answer should be 9hours, or 540minutes (9*60).
Instead, my formula counts backwards, grabbing the duration from 6am to 9pm which is 15hours, or 900min.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQOiv.png) is what I have so far. The formula on F2 works just fine until you cross midnight in C2. For example, if B2 is 9pm and C2 is 11pm, F2 is 120minutes. Once you change C2 to 12pm (0:00 in 24hour notation), the calculation flips and becomes 540minutes.

I'm thinking since the cells like to count backwards, I could maybe take 24 hours and subtract it by the value in F2, effectively getting back the other portion?

I stumbled into a weird pseudo-fix: if B2 is 21:00 (9pm) and I put 30:00 into C2, C2 displays 6:00 and F2 counts properly. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOZ9z.png) is what that looks like. I am hoping to find a better solution than this-- the UX i'm looking to achieve is just putting my bed time and my wake time and the cells do the rest.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `abs`.

```
C2-B2
```

already assumes next day when `C2<B2` as shown here: [image]

*The reason it works is that Google Sheet treats those as (duration of) time. And when displaying time, the "minus amount" is converted to a positive time value that represents a time of the previous day, as if modulus 24 hours. For example, 7:00 (hour) minus 21:00 (hour) gives -14:00 (hour) and it will be displayed as 24:00 (hour) - 14:00 (hour) = 10:00 (hour). Thus it is equivalent to the number you are looking for. However, modulus 24 hours effect is only for display. The minus sign is still inherent to the resultant value.*

---

In order to display minutes or do other calculations with the result, you can wrap it with [`timevalue()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350?hl=en). With that, the underlying value will be converted as described above.

To then display minutes, you can format the cell to display `Elapsed minutes` using the steps shown below.

[image]

[image]

And you will see minutes in the cell as shown below.

[image]

---

Your question implies that you may desire to do calculations on the result.

If that is that case, it helps to know that the output of `timevalue` is time duration in (fractions of) days without any inherent formatting. If not, you may skip the followings.

For example, in the preceding image, if you put `=C1*2` in `D1`, with automatic formatting, `D1` will inherit the format of `C1`, which was `Elapsed minutes`. You will thus see 1440. However, the actual underlying value is 1 because the real meaning of the data is half a day times 2. And you can confirm that by setting the format of `D1` as `numbers`.

Thus, if you are only doing calculations with outputs of `timevalue`, you are fine without worrying about the above. However, if you mix the result of `timevalue` with other types of data, the fraction of day meaning is what will be used in your calculations.

Comment: Even with abs removed it does not assume next day when C2<B2. The math counts backwards, so instead of time in bed being 9 hours (540minutes) from 9pm-6am, it says 9pm-6am = 15 hours (900minutes). What it's doing is counting as if I start at 6am and end at 9pm. This backwards flip occurs every time you cross midnight.

Comment: @codenamekale: Ah, I made a typo. I do mean `C2-B2`.

Comment: even so, this does not solve the problem

Comment: @codenamekale: See edits.

Comment: FANTASTIC. Thank you so much for taking the time on that edit, I see now what I was doing wrong!